# How to detect when the div element width change (not window resize) in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I have a scenario, if div element width changes, i need to perform some functionality. So is there any way to detect that element width changes (not window resize).

for Example, 
I have a DIV element with the width 300px and my window is 800px while rendering the page. When i trigger a function, i changed the div element width to 400px, so for that default width change i need to perform some actions, so is there any way to detect in pure javascript for the element size change ?

Comment: how do you change the width? Do you set an inline style?

Comment: yes, i am doing like this `style.width = "400px"`

Comment: You could always fire a custom event from the same place you change the width, and listen for that event elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  Consider the following example that will let you know when the `<p>` tag is resized manually or when you click the "Resize" button.  Any attribute mutation will trigger the observer so you will need to filter by what you want.

```js
const p = document.querySelector("p");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

const p$ = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
  for (mutation of mutationList) {
    console.log(mutation);
  }
});

p$.observe(p, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: false,
  subtree: false
});

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  p.style.width = "100px";
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
}

.resizable {
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="resizable">Hello</p>
  <button>Resize</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, unless the value used is dynamic or stylesheet-defined (e.g. `%`, `vh`, `vw`, `animation`, `transition`, `@media`, `var()`, etc.)

Comment: @FZs Hmm, yes, you're right.  I'll wait for the OP to say if those cases need to be addressed.  You could add `animationiteration` or another Animation event listener.  The `%` based ones would be particularly tricky.

Comment: @zero298, as you mentioned, is there a way to check the parent handler width change, when the div will become the 100% width to parent ?.

Answer (score 7):

The perfect solution would be a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), because it's more efficient than polling, and can detect changes due to dynamic CSS units, transitions, animations, etc. as well.

And as of 2022, [it's already supported in all mainstream browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver).

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('#sizeobserver')

new ResizeObserver(console.log).observe(elem)
```

```css
#sizeobserver {
   resize: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="sizeobserver">Resize me!</div>
```

To ignore height changes, you can check for the `width` property of the `contentRect`. Now only the width's changes get logged:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('#sizeobserver')
{ // <--Just to encapsulate prevWidth
  let prevWidth
  new ResizeObserver(changes => {
    for(const change of changes){
      if(change.contentRect.width === prevWidth) return
      prevWidth = change.contentRect.width

      //Code here:
      console.log(change)
    }
  }).observe(elem)
}
```

```css
#sizeobserver {
   resize: both;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="sizeobserver">Resize me!</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely the solution for today's modern development (May 2022) and is now widely supported. Oh the things I can do with this feature; I can just picture it.
It brings Flutter's layoutBuilder (if you know you know) to the DOM (or vice-versa...depending on which came first)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `MutationObserver` instance and look for any change of the `style` attribute

```js
var element = document.getElementById('d');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
   console.log("You changed the style") 
});


observer.observe(element, { attributeFilter: ['style'] });


setTimeout(()=>{
   element.style.width = '400px';
}, 2000)
```

```css
#d {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #9bc;
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

If you instead apply a `class` with the given width then listen to any change of the class in the `attributeFilter`.

Comment: That works, unless the value used is dynamic or stylesheet-defined (e.g. `%`, `vh`, `vw`, `animation`, `transition`, `@media`, `var()`, etc.)

Comment: yes, it is tailored to the specific use case of the OP as they specified in their comment